# How to load 50,000 records in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to & learning Angular.

I have an API which will fetch 50K records from the database. In the front end I have two components

SearchComponent -> Search filters are provided and filtered data can be seen.

FormComponent -> If we click on particular record in the search component mat table , then respective id is sent to the API, and it fetches data of that particular record and display the data in the form.

As of now, there is no relationship between the two components.

So, If i click on the record I will be moved to form route and if i go back to search route my search filters and mat table data is lost. Again I need to fill all the search filters and for loading data in the table takes time as well.Which is not the best practice.

Any suggestions where if i move back to search route the data is persistent

Comment: Without knowing anything about your app it does not sound like a good idea to handle 50k records in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, if you are new and learning Angular, as you said - I would strongly recommend against loading  50K records in Angular Material table. Depending how complex the table is (that is, how many columns, how complex the columns are, whether they are sortable, etc.) the sweet spot is between 1,000 and 5,000 records. Anything above that causes significant delay (at least 30 seconds; could be several minutes). Better limit the number of records returned from the server and implement pagination.

**Second**, what is the relevancy of form functionality to your question? Just the fact that it is *not* a one-time load, but you would need to load the table again and again? Even more reasons *not* to load it in the first place.

**Finally** (and that's why I put this as an answer, rather than a comment) - if you truly decide to load large number of records, you can use `ngx-infinite-scroll`. It will allow you to load just a screenful of records, and the system will continue to load the rest (similar the way Facebook does it). But I would recommend to get help from more experienced Angular developer... or not do it at all!

Comment: Thank You @Felix, On the first go I'm fetching only 10 columns data from db and displaying in mat table. Once the table record is clicked, then I will be passing thr id of that record to api , fetching 30 columns data and displaying it in the form. The issue is if i move back to the search route my existing search filters and mat table data is lost. Is there a way to persist the data ? Because loading the records again will take lot of time

Comment: my experience is that once you go back, the datatable object is already built and is rendered quickly... but YMMV